# Error / warning messages on git push

Tags: git

When I perform a successful `git push`, I receive the following messages.

> remote: /usr/bin/env: ruby: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
>
> error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory

Why is it looking for ruby and why is it trying to perform some post-receive hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is running a server side hook (`post-receive`) on the remote that you are pushing to. The hook requires ruby to be run. You will have to contact the administrator of the git repo that you are pushing to.

If you own the remote repo, or you want to give instructions to the admin, checkout the `.git` dir or the root of the repo and the `hooks` folder under it. The `post-receive` hook may be removed if not required.

Comment: Check out if you have a a hooks subdir inside your project's .git dir, it should be there.